# I am trying to deploy a python web app to Google App Engine . It works locally but I cannot get it to host .gives a build error on instance

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine

When I try to deploy to GAE, with :

```
gcloud app deploy
```

on the cmd line, it errors after some minutes during the build.
I can run it locally on my Mac (mojave 10.14.3) just fine - on localhost
Locally I use python 3.6 and latest pip (19.1.1) for packages

The gcloud instance is an Ubuntu machine running either python 2.7 or 3.6. 
In my app.yaml config file i set to python 3.

The app.yaml file is :

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn app:app.server -b :$PORT

threadsafe: false

runtime_config:
  python_version: 2


resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 1
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

the requirements.txt file is :

```
dash==0.21.0
dash-core-components==0.22.1
dash-html-components==0.10.0
dash-renderer==0.12.1
Flask==0.12
pandas==0.22.0
plotly==2.5.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
flask_login==0.4.1
flask_sqlalchemy==2.4.0
configparser==3.7.4
arrow==0.14.2
dash-daq==0.1.5
sqlalchemy==1.3.4
scipy==0.17.0
numpy==1.16.4
pillow==6.0.0
dash_daq==0.1.5 
certifi==2019.3.9
retrying==1.3.3
urllib3==1.25.3
requests==2.22.0
```

I've tried basically everything! from switching both my local to python 2.7 and the cloud config.

All combinations of app.yaml configs.I fixed all package errors that came up.

I expect possibly, that it may be that I somehow need to do a custom environment build via a .Dockerfile.  but its not clear what customisation exactly is needed. Also its v frustrating as each time I try it takes several minutes to attempt to deploy..(any advice to speed up ??)

My "main" (app.py) file :

```
# index page
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import sys

#sys.path.append('/Users/crowledj/Mindfule/dash-flask-login/views/')
#sys.path.append('/Users/crowledj/Mindfule/dash-flask-login/flask_login/')

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)


#server=app.server

#app.css.append_css({'external_url': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css'})


from server import app, server
from flask_login import logout_user, current_user
import success, login, login_fd, logout
```

For the imports , and the final line to actually run it is :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=    False,port=8080,host= "foodmoodai.appspot.com")
```

The imports of my main app code file:

```
import dash
#import dash_auth
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_daq as daq
import plotly.graph_objs as go

from textwrap import dedent as d

from flask import Flask
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from NutrientParser import parseNutrientStr_frmUser,parseResearch,parseFoodResearch,find_substring
from userMindfuleClasses import *
#import time
#import dash_table as dtable
#import base64
import PIL  
import urllib3
from PIL import Image
import json,os
import arrow


from server import app
```

The main error in the build logs is that the scipy build fails ...:

```
Step #1:   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scipy: started
Step #1:   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scipy: finished with status 'error'
Step #1:   Complete output from command /env/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-m9tl_bsf/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-db6mbz4m --python-tag cp36:
Step #1:   Traceback (most recent call last):
Step #1:     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Step #1:     File "/tmp/pip-install-m9tl_bsf/scipy/setup.py", line 265, in <module>
Step #1:       setup_package()
Step #1:     File "/tmp/pip-install-m9tl_bsf/scipy/setup.py", line 253, in setup_package
Step #1:       from numpy.distutils.core import setup
Step #1:   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
Step #1:   
Step #1:   ----------------------------------------
Step #1:   Failed building wheel for scipy
Step #1:   Running setup.py clean for scipy
```

Another clue lies above this in the full error logs.

It also stated that I have an old version of pip on the instance and that a much more up to date one exists. How can this be done - i.e updated on the instance?!

BTW - I checked the logs in ,my app engine console and its the same details  :(

Comment: Since numpy and scipy are dependency of pandas, you should move them up before pandas..

Comment: Thanks , I have another issue with this deployment now. I have seen it here on SO, but I have tried all the suggested solutions and failed .  Desperately in need of help, any suggestions.  I am trying to display a couple of static images  on the initial page of my web app. They ahe not showing at all instead giving the usual 'image not found icon' and ''error occurred trying to load this resource in the inspect element. My app.yaml fill his the same as above but with the following appended , handlers:
- url: /imgages
  static_dir: imgages

- url: /.*
  script: app.app

Comment: a actually this is my complete current app.yaml file :                                          runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn app:app.server -b :$PORT

threadsafe: false

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 1
  disk_size_gb: 10

handlers:
- url: /imgages
  static_dir: imgages

- url: /.*
  script: app.app

Comment: @DavyCorkboi Please ask a new question, you'll be more likely to get a response.